# Why are the instances on the right side turned 90 degrees?

Tags: modeling, instances

The instancing objects were mirrored over so they should be identical. The rotations are all 0 0 0.
[image]

Comment: hello, could you please be a little bit more precise, waht objects are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mirror modifier then the particles may not work properly until you apply the mirror modifier.